# How do I close the modal from the backdrop?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a modal, and once it open i'm able to close it via the close button or the x. However, I would also like to be able to close it by clicking on the backdrop. Here is the code i have so far to close the modal.

```
    function close_modal() {
        jQuery('#details-modal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#details-modal').remove();
            jQuery('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        },500);
    }
```

Comment: You are describing default behavior. Create demo that shows modal not closing when clicked outside. See [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think will give you an idea of how it would work

```
 function myfunction() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `if` statement is invalid